# How to change Path Fill Color in a ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a lot of shapes that I have to reuse in a `ResourceDictionary`. My questions is basically if there is a better way to change the Fill Color of the shape than the following:

Styles.xaml

```
<Path x:Key="ShapeTick"
          Width="36"
          Height="29.17"
          Data="M36.068-15.439l1.993,2.263L14.393,13.731,2.061-.3,4.053-2.564,14.393,9.154Z"
          Stretch="Fill" />
```

View.xaml

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ShapeTick}}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource SGreen}"/>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a *Style* resource:

```
<Style x:Key="PathStyle" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="36" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="29.17" />
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M36.068-15.439l1.993,2.263L14.393,13.731,2.061-.3,4.053-2.564,14.393,9.154Z" />
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
</Style>
```

...and apply this one to your `Path` elements with different colours:

```
<Path Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" Fill="Red" />
<Path Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" Fill="Blue" />
```

Comment: Thanks, as always.

Could you tell me what is the differences between using a Style and using a Path object directly or what should be a better practice?

Comment: Well, in short a Style is a Style gets applied to elements of a certain type and a Path is an instance of an element.